# DropdownButton<String> not changing value onChanged

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working with a DropDownButton, I have created a showModalBottomSheet that is called whenever I press the Add button. Inside of these Sheet I have inserted some textfields and a dropDownButton. The data from this sheet will be sent to firestore. 
I could successfully create the DropDownButton. But when pressed it doesn't change to the value I have selected.
The function:

```
void _CreateButtons(context){

    TextEditingController _buttonName = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _comodoName = TextEditingController();
    String _iconName;
    var _icons = ['None', 'Lock', 'LightBulb', 'Check', 'Cold', 'Alarm', 'Television', 'Bed'];
    var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext bc){
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 20, 12, 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        maxLength: 10,
                        controller: _buttonName,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Button name",
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ),
                        validator: (val){
                        if (val.length == 0){
                          return "Button name cannot be empty";
                        }else{
                          return null;
                        }
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      TextFormField( 
                        maxLines: 1,
                        maxLength: 20,                       
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        controller: _comodoName,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Room name",
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                        ),
                        validator: (val){

                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  items: _icons.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: dropDownStringItem,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(getIconData(dropDownStringItem)),
                          Text(dropDownStringItem),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),

                  onChanged: (String name){
                    setState(() {
                      _iconName = name;
                    });
                  },
                  value: _iconName,
                ),
```

I call this function inside the stageful widget:

```
Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenSize/1.2, top: screenSize*1.7),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0F52BA),
                    onPressed: (){
                      _CreateButtons(context);
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  )
                ),
```

The _CreateButtons is inside the Stageful widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have used function to render UI and store state. But when you call `setstate` it rebuild all you UI of StatefulWidget. That is why your function - `_CreateButtons` called again with the same value. That is why, you should add all your bottom sheet code to different `StatefulWidget` to handle states correctly.

1. Move your codes to any StatefulWidget:

```dart
class MyCustomBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _MyCustomBottomSheetState();
}

class _MyCustomBottomSheetState extends State<MyCustomBottomSheet> {
  
    TextEditingController _buttonName = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController _comodoName = TextEditingController();
    String _iconName;
    var _icons = ['None', 'Lock', 'LightBulb', 'Check', 'Cold', 'Alarm', 'Television', 'Bed'];
    var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(/// UI codes of build buttons);
  }
}
```

2. and call this widget when your `FloatingActionButton` pressed like following:

```dart
 FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0F52BA),
                    onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (ctx) => MyCustomBottomSheet()),
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
          
                )
```

Comment: How could I perform that, could you please elab

Comment: remove `CreateButtons` function and move all your code inside of it to new `StatefulWidget` for example called `MyCustomBottomSheet`. And In this case your state will work correctly.

Comment: but my return will be a `showModalBottomSheet(context, bc)`?

Comment: I have added example to my answer above.